# Use full titles for Telltale's [the-walking-dead]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I propose renaming the tags for [Telltale's The Walking Dead series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_(video_game_series)) to use the full titles.

- [the-walking-dead](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead) -> [the-walking-dead-season-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-season-one)
- [the-walking-dead-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-2) -> [the-walking-dead-season-two](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-season-two)
- [the-walking-dead-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-3) -> [the-walking-dead-a-new-frontier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-a-new-frontier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did the following:

- [the-walking-dead](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead) → [the-walking-dead-season-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-season-one)

  - Made [the-walking-dead](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead) a synonym.
- [the-walking-dead-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-2) → [the-walking-dead-season-two](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-season-two)

  - Made [the-walking-dead-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-2) a synonym.
- [the-walking-dead-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-3) → [the-walking-dead-a-new-frontier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-a-new-frontier)

  - Made [the-walking-dead-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-3) a synonym.